# Just upgraded to 22.04, "Backups" from previous version keeps crashing

Tags: 22.04, backup, restore

I recently used Backups to back up all my data from an older version of Ubuntu, then upgraded to 22.04 lts. There are some large folders within this back up and whenever I try to restore even one folder, I get the "Backups is not responding, wait or force quit" error message, I have been able to restore the smaller folders but all I have left is the larger ones. The entire backup is about 160gigs. I have even tried saving the backup file from my external hard drive to the local hard drive to see if that would help, but no change.

Comment: Please elaborate on how you did the backup and how you are trying to restore it.

Comment: Sure thing @Pilot6, I used the Backups program, and had all my files to be included and none excluded in the backup, and had backed up to an external hard drive, then I plugged my external hard drive into a PC with an upgraded version of Ubuntu (22.04) and I'm using the same Backups program already installed, and using the restore choice, and restoring to a local folder, first I was restoring directly from the external drive, but now I'm restoring from a local folder that I had copied the backup folder from the external hard drive. The later seems to be working better.